# Escape special (HTML tag) characters in XML attribute?

Tags: html, xml, encoding

As part of an XML node attribute, I need to pass up HTML characters as part of an attribute value, such as hello" />. I can't use CDATA as part of the value of the  node, as lots of other systems use this method and I cannot afford to break or rewrite that process, so I'm stuck with this.

I can't HTML encode the values, as they're used inside of an email and are subsequently outputted literally as HTML encoded values (<br >hello, for example).

Is there a way to escape HTML (specifically, the < character) and allow me to keep un-encoded HTML inline as an attribute? Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to have unmodified HTML in a HTML attribute, while the HTML should be escaped (=modified)? That sounds like a contradiction. What prevents you from using `&lt;`?

Comment: unmodified HTML inside of an XML attribute. I can't html encode it, as it will go into the email as html encoded as well.

Comment: So, `<x y="<z>">` is not changed, and `<x y="&lt;z&gt;">` is replaced with `<x y="&amp;lt;z&amp;gt;">`? That sounds inconsistent. Can you add examples of the input-ouput pairs to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML characters `<>&"` must be escaped identical to the HTML entities `&lt;` and so on. Using XML APIS will receive/store the original character. Other character entities in HTML should be converted to UTF-8. Numeric entities, hex (`&#xFC;`) and decimal (`&#2285;`) are simple, but for named entities (`&bull;`) one needs a Library. (If one wants to achieve completeness.)